# Collection element of type 'CGSize' is not an Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, nsdictionary, cgsize

I'm trying a give a NSDictionary key value a CGSize, and XCode is giving me this error. My code:

```
       NSArray *rows = @[
        @{@"size" : (CGSize){self.view.bounds.size.width, 100}
          }
        ];
```

Why am I getting an error here? If its impossible to store a CGSize in a dict, then what's an alternative approach?

**EDIT:**
now getting "Used type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize') where arithmetic, pointer, or vector type is required" error with this code:

```
NSDictionary *row = rows[@0];
CGSize rowSize = [row[@"size"] CGSizeValue] ? : (CGSize){self.view.bounds.size.width, 80};
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`CGSize` is not an object. It's a C struct. If you need to store this in an obj-c collection the standard way is by wrapping it in `NSValue`, like so:

```
NSArray *rows = @[
 @{@"size" : [NSValue valueWithCGSize:(CGSize){self.view.bounds.size.width, 100}]
  }
];
```

Then later when you need to get the `CGSize` back, you just call the `-CGSizeValue` method, e.g.

```
CGSize size = [rows[0][@"size"] CGSizeValue];
```

Comment: It really is a shame you can't put an arbitrary C struct into an objective-c object using the new literal syntax. The only real difficulty I would see is dealing with selectors to get it out.

Comment: What about assigning a block as the value which returns the CGSize? Sort of like a "Lambda" in Python

Comment: @yourfriendzak: That seems a bit absurd.

Comment: @KevinBallard why? An inline anonymous function (aka "block" in obj-c) sounds like a perfectly valid value.

Comment: @yourfriendzak: It would work, but what benefit is there to that?

Comment: @KevinBallard because it could be used to return more than just CGSizes. Might be easier than having to remember and use specific NSValue methods for every non-object type you want to store.

Comment: @yourfriendzak: The vast majority of structs stored in collections are `CGSize`, `CGRect`, and `CGPoint`, all of which are handled by `NSValue`.

Comment: @KevinBallard yeah, you're probably right, I was just exploring alternatives

Comment: Trying CGSizeValue, I'm getting this error now: Used type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize') where arithmetic, pointer, or vector type is required

Comment: @KevinBallard added my code as an edit in the original question

Comment: @yourfriendzak: You're using the `CGSize` value as the conditional of a ternary, which means you're trying to interpret it as an integral value (which is what booleans are in C). Structs can't be treated as integral values, hence the error. You probably meant to say `row[@"size"] ? [row[@"size"] CGSizeValue] : (CGSize){...}`

Comment: @KevinBallard but according to the docs "A GNU extension to C allows omitting the second operand, and using implicitly the first operand as the second also:" Shouldn't the behavior be the same regardless of whether there's a second operand?

Comment: @yourfriendzak: That means you can say `foo ?: bar` and it's equivalent to `foo ? foo : bar` (while only evaluating `foo` once). But that doesn't work here because you want to test the value `row[@"size"]`, and then call a method on it if `non-nil`, or return another value if `nil`.

Comment: It's more correct to use the CGSizeMake function than the arbitrary struct definition shown here.

Comment: @Augmental: What do you mean by "more correct"? Both are equally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer only works on iOS;  for Mac OS X (Cocoa) do:

```
[NSValue valueWithSize:NSMakeSize(self.view.bounds.size.width, 100)];
```